# Android Service to play music and stop on Pause and on Stop

Tags: android, service, media-player, android-mediaplayer

I am implementing MediaPlayer class in my app and I want music played on background, so I used Service instead of Activity or BroadcastReciever. Now the problem is, if user exist or pause the app, music playing on without stopping. I did add onStop and onPause methods, but the problem keeps. And I can't call super.onPause() method like I do in Activity class.

After some research I found out service keeps active even app pauses or stops.(I don't know this is true) but with my experience I think this is true. What should I do? I searched google and stackoverflow for an answer but couldn't get an answer.

Here is a code.

```
 package in.isuru.animation;

 import android.app.Service;
 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.media.MediaPlayer;
 import android.os.IBinder;
 import android.util.Log;

 public class PlayMusic extends Service{

private static final String TAG = null;
MediaPlayer player;

public void onCreate(){
    super.onCreate();
    Log.d(TAG, "Music service started onCreate()");
    player = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.oh_holy_night);
    player.setLooping(true);
    //player.setVolume(100, 100);
}

public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId){
    player.start();
    Log.d(TAG, "Player started!");
    if(player.isLooping() != true){
        Log.d(TAG, "Player not playing any file.");
    }
    return 1;
}

public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId){

}

public IBinder onUnBinder(Intent arg0){
    return null;
}

public void onStop(){
    player.stop();
    player.release();
}

public void onPause(){

    player.stop();
    player.release();

}

public void onDestroy(){
    player.stop();
    player.release();
    Log.d(TAG, "Player destroyed");
}

public void onLowMemory(){
    player.release();
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {

    return null;
}

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off you never have the option to do anything long running in a BroadcastReceiver because the system will not like you.
So I'm a little confused. You want the music to be playing in the background so you used a Service. That is correct.
But now you say that when the user exits or pauses your activity the music is still playing? Well yes it will, isn't that the reason you put it in a Service to begin with??

You have 2 options. You can move the calls to start and stop your media player in onStart()/onResume() and onPause()/onStop() of your activity. That will only play music when the Activity has the foreground.

Your second option is to keep the MediaPlaying in the Service. However, you will need to send an Intent to your Service to let it know when to stop playing music. The best way todo this is pack up a PendingIntent to give to the Notification Manager that will start an Activity which has buttons on it that will pause and play your music. If you do not provide a way for the use to get back to an Activity that controls a service then your music will play to the end and user will not have a nice way to turning it off.

Comment: Well, my Main Activity is an animation, will it work with UI thread if I play music on that activity?

Comment: Well almost. By default a Service also runs on the UI thread. A Service by itself does not get off loaded to it's own thread. Since you are doing CPU intense MP3 playback you will have to create a new Thread in which you start this service. This new class will have to take a Context so that it can start and control the Activity as well. I would suggest having your Activity implement Runnable (instead of extending Thread). This should allow you some more flexibility and reuse of your variables.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I will use Activity instead of Service. Thank you for explanation!

Comment: Well you only want to use an Activity instead of a Service if you want the media player to have the same life cycle as the Activity. (i.e. it's only playing when the Activity is on the screen). What I was talking about for your Activity (or a sub class for that matter) was to implement runnable instead of extending Thread. I highly suggest that you use your media player within a Service started within it's own Thread. Hope that clears things up.

Comment: @FrankSposaroMSFT What if I want the `Service` to stop when I minimise the app or destroy it but not when I switch to another `Activity`? I want the music to play throughout my app.

Comment: @edwoolard I made the jump to world of Windows so I'm a little rusty on my Android. However, I believe services should still run in the background of other Activities aka Google Music player does this. If your service is stopping you may have to give it a special property

Answer (score 0):

The problem is communication.
You used `player.start()` in `onStartCommand()`,hence the service can start playback.

**Stop/pause music** has never been communicated to the Service and hence the problem.